# Is it possible to get the latest value from every column in a one to many relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Using this data set:

```
| RECID |  ID  | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE3 |                          RECDT |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1 | 1-01 |      1 |      2 |      3 | January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|     2 | 1-01 |      3 | (null) | (null) | January, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|     3 | 1-01 | (null) | (null) |      1 | January, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Is it possible to return the following result with a simple query?

```
|  ID  | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE3 |
-----------------------------------
| 1-01 |      3 |      2 |      1 |
```

The data set needs to return the latest value for each column based off of a date and PtID.  So, for example, if I was interested in all changes to a PTID until January, 02, 2013, the result would look like this:

```
|  ID  | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE3 |
-----------------------------------
| 1-01 |      3 |      2 |      3 |
```

The schema has been started on [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ee9a) for anyone interested.

Comment: Which SQL Version are you using?

Comment: @NitinMidha MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that would work in many dialects of SQL:

```
select ptid,
       (select value1 from t t2 where t2.ptid = t.ptid and value1 is not null order by recdt desc limit 1
       ) as Value1,
       (select value2 from t t2 where t2.ptid = t.ptid and value2 is not null order by recdt desc limit 1
       ) as Value2,
       (select value3 from t t2 where t2.ptid = t.ptid and value3 is not null order by recdt desc limit 1
       ) as Value3
from t
where ptid = '1-01'
group by ptid
```

Some databases might prefer `top` or `recnum =  1` instead of `limit`.

In MySQL, you can also do:

```
select ptid,
       substring_index(group_concat(value1 order by recdt desc), ',', 1) as Value1,
       substring_index(group_concat(value2 order by recdt desc), ',', 1) as Value2,
       substring_index(group_concat(value3 order by recdt desc), ',', 1) as Value3
from t
group by ptid
```

This would have the side effect of turning the values into character strings.  You could cast back to your desired type.  Also, if the values might contain commas, then you would want to use a different separator.

Comment: Are there performance concerns with running that many subqueries?

Comment: @afuzzyllama . . . If you have an index on `ptid, recdt`, then performance should not be a big issue.  Each subquery would be resolved by loading the same records into memory and scanning them; the records would already be in the cache once the first subquery is run.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!  I thought about doing it this way, but don't have enough background to know if subqueries like that are the way to go.

Comment: Your first query returns one result for each row in the db(http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc5d7/1), you might want to add distinct somewhere.

Comment: @JakubKania . . . I added a `group by`.  Thank you for the observation.  I was so focused on he other columns, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an aproach that would work in many dialects of SQL without subqueries and producing only one row of output.

```
SELECT f1.value1,f3.value2,f5.value3 FROM FUNTIMES f1 
LEFT JOIN funtimes f2 ON
f1.recdt<f2.recdt AND f2.value1 IS NOT NULL
JOIN funtimes f3 ON f1.ptid=f3.ptid
LEFT JOIN funtimes f4 ON
f3.recdt<f4.recdt AND f4.value2 IS NOT NULL
JOIN funtimes f5 ON f1.ptid=f5.ptid
LEFT JOIN funtimes f6 ON
f5.recdt<f6.recdt AND f6.value3 IS NOT NULL
WHERE f1.value1 IS NOT NULL AND f2.value1 IS NULL
AND f3.value2 IS NOT NULL AND f4.value2 IS NULL
AND f5.value3 IS NOT NULL AND f6.value3 IS NULL;
```

Compare to the one above: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ee9a/34